# Safety/Quality issues by modding PC PSU to be floating.

Tags: power-supply, safety, grounding

Since I don't have enough money at the moment to purchase a good bench power supply, I want to 'mod' a PSU. In the first instance not by opening the PSU, but just by making an adapter that also puts a load on it's 5V rail.

But after taking a closer look (with a multimeter) I found an issue that could be a problem. In contrast to bench supplies (from my University) I'm familliar with a PSU is not floating. It's ground outputs are connected directly to ground.

This could be a very big problem if I mistakenly connect the ground hook of a probe to a higher potential point, thus creating a short which probably will evaporate the probe lead. I know myself, this will happen someday.

As for the  AC side I think without opening it should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSklpr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where the Live, Neutral and Earth wire are labeled, My personal safety simply modeled as a resistor, and a failure that should trigger the RCD/Circuit-breaker as a switch.
RLOAD being of course an very basic simplification of the rest of the circuit.

Now for my question: Are there any issues that could occur by making the modification:

- Lifting the Earth from the neutral line @RLOAD
- Keeping the Earth connected to the metal chassis of the supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXDQEQ.png)</sup>

Are there also concerns with quality/stability. As in +5 or +12V rails being way out of spec when measured?

I've been thinking about this for some hours and I think there wouldn't be any major issues, but since I do not have a background or vast knowledge in power supply design I'd like to hear your take on this.

Comment: What is the "Potential disaster" switch intended to represent? There is nothing like that in any normal PC PSU.

Comment: I probably could have left it out, but it's just as an representation to me: An unknown event where the Earth/Chassis could get, due to mechanical/electrical failure, shorted to the mains. It is drawn in these two schematics as a method to see if my hand has a problem if this event happens. I think there is no really big problem, in contrast to when I would lift the ground 'earlier' than at the neutral node at RLOAD, but since I don't have a lot knowledge about electrical safety I want to ask.

Comment: @brhans: your average terribly cheap china smps has this switch, it is otherwise known as "cut off tth component leads stuck in flux residues instead of being cleaned up"